# How can I throw away local changes in my Git repository when pulling a new version from github?

Tags: git, workflow, github

I've started to learn git in the past few days and I have a basic question.

Imagine this situation:

You create an empty folder and in there you create a foo.txt file.

In order to push the data into the remote repository (e.g. github), you make the following commands:

- `git init` -> in order to initalize the repository in the folder
- `git add .` -> in order to add to  the index all the files in the folder, in this case foo.txt
- `git commit -m "First commit"` -> We make the first commit
- `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/gitrepository.git` -> We add the github repository
- `git push origin master` -> We push the changes to the remote repository

  1. Now in the github repository you have only a foo.txt file.
  2. So now you are in another machine and want to use the repository, so you create an empty folder and pull the data from the remote repository. 
     Then you create a file named bar.txt, delete foo.txt, add the file (bar.txt) to the index, make a commit and push the changes to the remote repository.
  3. Now in the repository we have only the bar.txt file
  4. But now in the first machine we still have the foo.txt file, and if we make a pull from the remote repository we have foo.txt and bar.txt.

But that's not what I would like to do, I would like to pull all the files from the repository and work only with those files. So in this example, if I only have now bar.txt in the repository, when I make a pull I don't want any other files in my project folder.

How do you manage that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you missed a step in 2.

You have to remove the foo.txt file from the index. It requires a specific command ("git add ." only puts file to the index but doesn't remove files) :

- git rm foo.txt
- git add -u (removes from the index all files that are not anymore in the workspace)

Then commit.

At step 3, after a pull on the first computer, the foo file should have disappeared.

Comment: I think I explained myself poorly. Imagine that you have in a repository only a bar.txt file, and at home you have your work directory with a foo.txt. If you make a pull from github, you would have both bar.txt and foo.txt in your working directory. But I don't want to do that, I would like to have the github repository clean each time I make a pull, meaning if I have only bar.txt in github, when I make a pull I only want bar.txt in my working folder and no more files.

Comment: A pull is a "fetch + merge". If I understand, you don't want a merge with your local changes.
Here is a way to do so, but I have to warn you: your local changes, even commited, will be lost.
FIRST :  "git fetch origin" (instead of pull). THEN : "git reset --hard origin/master".

Answer (score 1):

The way git works you will *always* have those files in your repository (i.e. in your repository's `.git` folder). The difference is that in step 4. once you pull changes, you are still left with your original working copy (git will only merge automatically if you have made no changes). I guess you are one merge away from what you want :)

I find this [Git Cheat-sheet](http://www.ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) very helpful.